# existence of identity for a binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

Let $E$ be a set equipped with a binary operation $*$ which is associative.

Assume that for any $a$ and $y$ in $E$, there exists $x$ in $E$ such that

$$y=a*x*a$$

Prove that $(E,*)$ has an identity element.

I don't know where / how to start, thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first move is always to try something simple, with fewer moving parts.  So let me first see what happens if $a = y$.  Then the condition becomes:  For any $a$, there is an $x$ such that $a = a*x*a$.  In that case, if there is to be an identity, $a*x$ would be a good candidate.  Can I perhaps show that $a*x*b = b$?  Not without some way of relating $a$ and $b$.  But I can use the condition again:  There is a $y$ such that $b = a*y*a$.  Let's try that:
$$
\begin{align}
a*x*b &= (a*x)*b\\
  &= (a*x)*(a*y*a)\\
  &= (a*x*a)*y*a\\
  &= a*y*a\\
  &= b.
\end{align}
$$
How about that!  $a*x$ is, at least, a left identity.

You can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder whether we necessarily have $a*x=x*a$ ?

Comment: You're welcome.  Just as $a*x$ is a left identity, $x*a$ is a right identity.  But when both exist, they must be equal: just multiply them together and see what happens.